# Vulnerabilities in Spring-web 5.3.30

Tags: spring-mvc, security

We are currently using Spring-web 5.3.30. jar in our project and it has some vulnerability. Spring 5.3.30 being the final version that supports jdk 8, when is the next patch release planned as a fix for the current vulnerability?